# Что значит ‹‹это не про меня››

Tags: перевод

Значит ли это букваьлно не касаться?

Comment: please provide some context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В зависимости от контекста эта фраза может означать:

- «то, что сказано, не относится ко мне», иначе говоря, «я не такой» («Неграмотный -- это не про меня»); либо
- «я недостоин этого», «я не заслуживаю этого» («Такая награда не про меня»).

Answer (score 3):

Это может ещё означать "это мне не подходит". Например, у Филатова:

> Мне бы шпагу, да коня,
>   Да на линию огня,
>   А дворцовые интрижки -
>   Это всё не про меня

Comment: Which is the same as "«то, что сказано, не относится ко мне», иначе говоря, «я не такой» («Неграмотный -- это не про меня»);" - from the answer by mustaccio